# How to read with ifstream into object member?

Tags: c++

The file opened in binary mode, the first variation gives exception, the second one is not.
How can I read directly to my mhead object with ifstream? Please help me. 
Here is my code:

```
class mhead {   

public:

  long length;  
  void readlong(std::ifstream *fp);
}  

void mhead::readlong(std::ifstream *fp)    
{
    //this one is not work
    fp->read((char*)this->length,sizeof(this->length));     

    //this is working
    long other;
    fp->read((char*)other,sizeof(other));
}
}
```

Comment: seems that you are writing to some random location in memory. It's just luck, that your second variant is working. Try fp-read(&this->length, sizeof(length)).

Comment: @Alexander: This approach does not seem like a very good idea. You are bound to stumble over compiler-implementation dependent differences. If you want to go about serialization in a portable and safe way, consider using [Boost.Serialization](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y I don't mean to be rude but introducing him to `Boost` is like taking his slingshot away (so he won't hurt himself) and giving him a cannon instead.

Comment: @cnicutar: Actually, introducing him to Boost is giving him a starting point from which he can learn how to write good C++. Most example in the Boost documentation are very good ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fp->read(&this->length,sizeof(this->length));
```

Writing to `(char *)this->length` means:

- Get some number you just made up
- Write to that memory location
- Hope for the best

Answer (score 0):

If read was successful `readlong` return true.

```
class mhead
{   
  public:
    long length;  

    bool readlong(std::istream &is)    
    {
      is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>( &this->length ), sizeof(long) );
      return ( is.gcount() == sizeof(long) )
    };
}
```

Or (I suggest this one):

```
istream & operator >> ( istream &is, mhead &_arg )
{
  long temp = 0;
  is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>( &temp ), sizeof(long) );
  if ( is.gcount() == sizeof(long) )
    _arg.length = temp;
  return is;
}
```